# All points y value undefined! in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm getting this error:

`line 0:all points y value undefined!`

My code for gnuplot is:

```
set terminal png 8;
set output "skript01_31/image10.png"; 
set timefmt x "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S";
set xdata time; 
set format x "%H:%M"; 
set xlabel "Cas"; 
set ylabel "Hodnota"; 
set yrange [:]; 
set xrange ["2009-05-11 07:30:00":"2009-06-11 00:34:00"]; 
set title "skript01"; 
set grid;
plot 'skript01_31/gnuplot_file' using 1:3 with points pt 7 ps 1 title "./skript01.sh";
```

My data file:

```
[2009-05-11 07:30:00] 0
[2009-05-11 07:31:00] 0.00999983333416666468
[2009-05-11 07:32:00] 0.01999866669333307936
[2009-05-11 07:33:00] 0.02999550020249566076
[2009-05-11 07:34:00] 0.03998933418663415945
[2009-06-11 00:34:00] 0.05
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time format, this should be `set timefmt x "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]";`, with the addition of the square brackets to match the time format used in the data file.  Additionally the `xrange` variable should also acquire additional square brackets to match: `set xrange ["[2009-05-11 07:30:00]":"[2009-06-11 00:34:00]"];`

Comment: Problem is here `set timefmt x "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S";`. There is missing brackets. Solution is `set timefmt x "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]";`
Thanks @ilent2

Comment: Ah yep, I see.  And the `using 1:3` is also correct.  I will rewrite this answer and mark as wiki post?